# What view is this and how can I implement it?

Tags: android, list, android-listview, android-view

[image]

What view is this and how can I implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks similar to CardView (https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html) with custom layout inside.

Answer (score 0):

That's a holo light frame layout with some views and TextViews inside of it.
You have to do you own formatting but this is a basic example.

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/exampleRL"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/firstDescription"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:text="Example text"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="12dp" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/Bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/firstDescription"
        android:background="#DCDCDC" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/secondDescription"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Bar"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:text="More text examples"
        android:textColor="#B0C4DE"
        android:textSize="12dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```